# In Windows 10, how can we set an application to be the default for all of its supported file types?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, file-association, user-interface, control-panel

I don't have much experience with the newer versions of Windows, and I'm having trouble doing something that I remember used to be possible in Windows 7.

When a program is installed, it was possible to set it as the default for every file type it supported by navigating to one button. For example, if we wanted to set Word to open all files it supports we click this:
[image: button]
In Windows 10, that doesn't work for two reasons:

- The settings are fragmented across two different applications. Navigating there in the control panel opens a different settings app.
- The new settings app is clunky. The "Set defaults by app" page does not allow someone to set *all* defaults at once and requires setting each file type one by one.

There must be a way to do what was possible before. Is there a solution, preferably one that doesn't involve navigating through some GUI?

Any solution is acceptable: registry hack, shell script, even a third-party tool. This is important because when there are hundreds of extensions to set, the existing UI is a non-starter.

Comment: Start, Settings, Apps.  Right side, scroll down to Choose Default App by File type. Open that (takes a half a minute). All the extensions are there and you can set them reliably.  You may have to set multiple extensions to to same app (Adobe comes to mind).

Comment: @John That doesn't help. From my question, "The new settings app is clunky. The 'Set defaults by app' page does not allow someone to set all defaults at once and requires setting each file type one by one." Please see the picture in my question. How do I set defaults for an app *all at once*?

Comment: @John All version of Windows, even earlier versions of Windows 10, used to support the functionality I'm asking about. Having many apps and many extensions has nothing to do with it; this is clearly a user interface problem.

Comment: What I described is the same in Windows 11 so things have changed from older versions and not going back.. sorry.

Comment: @ayane_m - What you want doesn’t exist for Windows 10+

Comment: If you want to get back the old interface, try the free [Default Programs Editor](https://defaultprogramseditor.com/) that implements it, and also does much more.

Comment: @harrymc That worked! If you turn that into an answer, you'll get the bounty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has created in Windows a new and more complicated mechanism
for setting default programs. The declared aim was to make it harder
for rogue programs to set themselves up as handlers for some protocols,
but it incidentally made it harder to move away from Microsoft's
then Internet Explorer browser.

A free product that implements the old interface is the
[Default Programs Editor](https://defaultprogramseditor.com/):

[image]

If that website will ever disappear from the internet,
the program can also be downloaded from
[MajorGeeks](https://m.majorgeeks.com/files/details/default_programs_editor.html)
and other websites.
A copy of the original website is also found on the
[Internet Archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20210712081800/https://defaultprogramseditor.com/).

Comment: the website is working and I just downloaded the app ;)

Comment: @Wayne: Must have been a momentary hiccup.

Comment: +1 for answering. The reason this is an important problem is because it's non-trivial to manually set each file type for one program when that program supports hundreds (or even thousands!) of file extensions. the time complexity of doing it should be O(1), not O(n).